# force update same route using route router v4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a click handler that navigate to item detail page.
`this.props.history.push('/item/${id}')`

And my item detail container have this

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (
    this.props.match.params.id &&
    prevProps.match.params.id !== this.props.match.params.id
  ) {
    this.props.fetchItems()
  }
}

render() {
    const { items } = this.props
    return <div>{items.map(o => <div>{o.name}</div>)}</div>
}
```

so if I click from `item/1` to `item/2` it will work, but when the page is already on `item/1`, I clicked `item/1`, the 
container isn't refresh, how to force that to happens?

Answer (score 0):

You are currently checking if the last id parameter differs from the current one, and then calling `fetchItems`. You could instead check if any other prop *except* `match.params.id` changed.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (/* any other prop except match.params.id changed */) {
    this.props.fetchItems()
  }
}
```

Comment: No, param.id won't change because item/1 to item/1 is still on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `window.location.reload()` ? So basically.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (
    this.props.match.params.id &&
    prevProps.match.params.id !== this.props.match.params.id
  ) {
    this.props.fetchItems()
  } else {
     location.reload();
   }
}
```

Comment: location.reload reload the entire page

Comment: and the condition is wrong also, try to understand the question again.